# How to make c# unit test as a standalone console program? (without external runner or console)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application

I want:

1. Make standalone unit-test console program.
   Direct run in console. **Without external test runner**.
2. Testing entrance is under control.

To demonstrate what I mean, for an example in C++ gtest:

- Fully embedded.
- Testing entrance is RUN_ALL_TESTS().
- Options is configurable by argv.

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv); 
return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NUnit:

```
return new NUnitLite.AutoRun().Execute(args);
```

https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/NUnitLite-Runner.html
Trivial but difficult to google.
I need "built-in" exact match to reach that document page.